# basic VBA code for copy&paste data to another sheet

Tags: vba

I know nothing about creating VBA codes from scratch, I only do them by recording my actions. However, the recording function can't seem to do what i wanted to happen on the report. I would like to ask for your help on how i could copy and paste specific data from my "Main Form" sheet to "Database" sheet.

I would like to copy the data from "Main Form" sheet (e3:e7,h3:h7,k3:k7,i12:i16,i18:i21,i23) and paste them in my "Database" sheet (a2:y2) when i click the "save" button from the "Main Form" sheet. This action must be repeated everytime we click the save button and the new set of data must go to the next empty row in "Database" sheet.

I hope someone could help me with this. unfortunately, i don't know how i can attach the file here.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test my suggestion yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `.Copy` method on non-contiguous ranges.

However, most times people want to "copy" something, all they really care about is transfering the values, which can be done without the copy/paste procedure (if you need to also copy formatting/etc., this could be done similarly as below).

Put this in the Workbook code module, not an ordinary code module, it has to go in the Workbook code module.  This calls a subroutine `TransferValues` every time you do a `Save` on your workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.Run "TransferValues"

End Sub
```

Put this in ordinary code module.

**REVISED**

I had to make some changes because of non-contiguous range, we need to iterate over the range's `.Areas` and then the individual cells within each of those.

```
Private Sub TransferValues()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet: Set wsMain = Sheets("Main Form")
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = Sheets("Database")
Dim rngToCopy As Range: Set rngToCopy = wsMain.Range("e3:e7,h3:h7,k3:k7,i12:i16,i18:i21,i23")
Dim c As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim lastRow As Long

Dim rngDestination As Range

'Get the last row in Database sheet:
lastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsData.Range("A:A"))
Set rngDestination = wsData.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Resize(1, 25).Offset(1, 0)

For Each ar In rngToCopy.Areas
    For Each cl In ar
        c = c + 1
        'I used this next line for testing:
        '  rngDestination.Cells(c).Value = cl.Address
        rngDestination.Cells(c).Value = cl.Value
    Next
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for attending to my question. However, after i followed the instructions you've given me as to where i should paste the codes, i noticed that it is only copying those in cell e3:e7...what should i do to make it copy all the data from the other cells?

Comment: @user2664641 I made a revision above. The problem was that the `.Cells.Count` behaves strangely on a non-continuous range.  Working with non-continuous ranges is a little tricky, but I think if we go over the range `Areas` and then the `Cells` within each Area, that should take care of it.

Comment: Hi David, i tried the revised code, but i suddenly got this error, "CAnnot run the Macro "Dummyfile1.xlsm!CopyPaste." :(

Comment: You didn't copy my code correctly, because there is no reference, anywhere, to a macro called "CopyPaste".  I made one other revision (worksheet names) so please try again, but be careful to use the code *exactly* as I have presented it.

Comment: I copied the codes the same way i did with the first one. i'm not sure why it is not working this time. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Revise your post to include the *ALL* code that you are actually now using, otherwise I have to try and guess what you've actually done because I did not provide **ANY** code that references a macro called `Dummyfile1.xlsm!CopyPaste`. If you have other code which is attempting to call this macro, if this macro does not actually exist, if a workbook `DummyFile1.xlsm` is not open at run-time, etc., there are a million-and-one things that might cause this particular error, but I am 100% certain it is not my code that raises this error, because my code does not call this procedure.

Comment: i tried to create another file and use your codes. but i still get the same error. i hope this is not too much to ask, but can i just send you the file instead?

Comment: Upload the file to Google Docs and post the URL here I'll take a look at it later.